# How would one go about outputting onclick Value to a .txt file?

Tags: javascript, html, output, user-input

I'm trying to construct a likert scale questionnaire to embed in a user study. I have coded it by using a onclick jscript function. It currently outputs the clicked on value to a text box, however I was wondering if it were possible to remove this and output the value directly to a separate .txt file in a manner that I could do the same for muliple questions collating the data in one file.

Code so far is as follows:

```js
function myFunction(answer) {
  document.getElementById("result").value = answer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Questionnaire</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h1 class="likert-header">This is a Likert Scale survey</h1>
      <form action="">
        <label class="statement">This HTML Likert scale is easy to use.</label>
        <ul class='likert'>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="likert1" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="1">
            <label>Strongly agree</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="likert1" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="2">
            <label>Agree</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="likert1" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="3">
            <label>Neutral</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="likert1" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="4">
            <label>Disagree</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="likert1" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="5">
            <label>Strongly disagree</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
    
      </form>
    </div>
    
    
      Your answer is: <input type="text" id="result">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
    </form>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Javascript isn't a file-based language, are you sure you mean "text file"?

Comment: Well any manner of outputting the radio button value to a separate file would be of use, I'm new to this and uncertain of how to go about it. I read that emailing it using php is an option but I really don't know ....

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new tab/window and outputting to that.

Comment: You need to send data to server and write to file or database there if you want to store data for all users. Use case is not very clear